# vim: set tag file name based on file name being edited

Tags: vim

I'm in a situation where the tag file for the file (say) `a.foo` is stored in file `a.foo.tags`. (Generated by a custom program that I've no control over.)

Is there a way for me to tell `vim` to look for tags in file `a.foo.tags` when editing `a.foo`? I've looked at `set tag` [help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'tags'), but it decidedly says that the tag file name cannot contain wildcards, nor I was able to use `expand('%:p')` tricks to set the tag file name appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the list of tag files with:

```
:exe 'set tags+='.expand('%').'.tags'
```

If the current file is `a.foo`, this command will add `a.foo.tags` to the tag file lookup list.